# How to setup foreign key (referential) constraints properly in Prisma using relation mode: "prisma"

Tags: mysql, express, prisma

Here are the snippets of my Prisma scheme

```
datasource db {
  provider     = "mysql"
  url          = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}

model User{
  id        String      @id @default(uuid())
  name      String
  age       Int
  SportData SportData[]
}

model SportData{
  id                   String    @id @default(uuid())
  userId               String
  user                 User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  createdAt            DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt            DateTime? @updatedAt
  caloryBurned         Int

  @@index([userId])
}
```

---

I have followed the guide in the [documentation here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/relation-mode) by making sure I put `@@index([userId])`

After I am doing my first migration using the command `npx prisma migrate dev --name "init"` and seeing the scheme created in MySQL Workbench, it shows that there are no foreign key (referential) constraints from `SportData:userId` to `User:id`. Moreover, I try to insert SportData row with the user id that did not exist in the User table and it inserts successfully instead of blocking (foreign key integrity)

Comment: "there are no foreign key (referential) constraints from SportData:userId to User:id. Moreover" which is expected behaviour for prisma mode.
"Moreover, I try to insert SportData row with the user id that did not exist in the User table and it inserts successfully instead of blocking (foreign key integrity)" did you do that using prisma client or direct DB query?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I did it using prisma client

Comment: I see. From docs "When you update a record, Prisma will emulate foreign key constraints ... However, when you create a record, Prisma does not emulate any foreign key constraints. You will be able to create invalid data."